Typical output characteristics table of an NPN transistor
The Ic - Vce table for the 2SC2411K transistor is given below.

As it is known the right side of the table represent the breakdown region. That is, does the Vce > 5 V region enter the breakdown region? In other words, according to the table, Vce cannot be more than 5 V. Am I thinking right?

When we determine Vce and Ib in the table, we can estimate Ic, but the datasheet says Ic (max) = 500 mA. The table gives a maximum value of 200 mA. How can I follow the Vce and Ib values for Ic = 500 mA in this graph?

Ib maximum 1 mA is given. Can't I go above 1 mA for Ib?



Source


In other words, according to the table, Vce cannot be more than 5 V.
Am I thinking right?

The safe operating area in the data sheet shows you the maximum voltage that can be applied for any given collector current: -


How can I follow the Vce and Ib values for Ic = 500 mA in this graph?

Use these two graphs to estimate what you need to know: -


Ib maximum 1 mA is given. Can't I go above 1 mA for Ib?

That is not a maximum value. If you look at the graphs above you can see that to get 500 mA of collector current with a saturation of 1 volt, the base current must be clearly over 5 mA.

for example, the point where the Ic of 0.01 A itersects with Vce of 10 V . this point is below the DC line, that means safe. Actually that point is below all of the lines so this point is safe for 1ms ,10 ms and 100 ms as well right ? did ı get it correct sir ? @Andy aka

@Mhan your assessment is correct.

Sir, there is a point which makes me very confused about the transistors. Generally ı am following  typical output characteristic table because I can easily predict the Beta from that table. This way make me design the transistor easily because Beta value is given for specific test conditions in datasheets. And in every video or document calculations made with B value. My question is can I make a prediction (extrapolate) for other Ic, Ib and Vbe values which are not given the same table ?for example  Vbe=15 V , Ic=300mA at proper Ib which are not given in the table ?  @Andy aka

when ı check the SOA table and decide for my proper Vce and corresponding Ic value,  I dont know my Ib  and beta value ( for the values not given in typical output characteristic). So I am having difficulties to design Rb ,Vb etc.  @Andy aka

@Mhan see my answer edit. I'm addressing the questions originally raised in your post.

@Mhan If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Sir one of this graph is for Vce= 3V pulse and the other is only for Vce of 5V ,3V, 1V.  My question as ı summarized above is how about the different Vce values like 10V ,15V ?  Different ranges are not given neither in table you showed nor typical characteristic table ? How will ı predict the Beta if my Vce , Ib or Ic is out of the range of tables ?  @Andy aka

I dont see any other Vce value other than 5,3,1 V in Figure 4. I dont see Vce of above 5V , ı dont see the Ic of above 200 mA, I dont see the Ib of above 1mA in the typical characteristics table. Did you get my point sir ? @ Andy aka

You are scatter-gunning issues that concern you without thinking hard-enough about these things. For instance, when Vce gets above a few volts (on this device about 5 volts), the beta relationship doesn't change. Look at all the information in the graphs and you will see this. Or, if that is too hard then raise a brand new post that explicitly targets that specific question @mhan

@Mhan if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.


The right side of the table does not represent a breakdown region. The chip can be used with VCE voltage up to 32V and Ic up to 500mA. But not simultaneously because it would overheat and melt the transistor. This just shows what you can expect with these typical operating points when pulsed. The voltage could go up to 32V, but it would be rather uninteresting as the lines would continue approximately linearly with same slope from 5V to 32V.

You can't follow this graph, as it is not for switching but linear operation. If you want 500mA IC, the electrical characteristics say you have max 600mV Vce and 50mA Ib. See Fig.6 which might be what you want.

Yes you can, and you need more than 1mA of Ib to drive 500mA Ic. See Fig.6.



how did you get 600 mV from Fig.6 , when ı follow beta=10 line  Vce is 200mV   @Justme

another thing is  Fig 6 includes only for 3 types of beta values ? how about the other beta values ? @Justme

@Mhan Figure 6 is about saturation, where β stops being relevant. That figure is about what saturation voltage you can expect at different "forced β", where you apply more base current than would be necessary in active mode. You can interpolate between the curves for other forced β values; it's not a good idea to rely on a precise saturation voltage anyway.

What about if we are not in saturation? lets say Ic=300 mA but this value is not drawn in the typical output characteristics table for given Ib as you can see. Can I extrapolate by looking at the curves given in the table ( up to Ib= 1mA, Vce=5 V and Ic=200 mA) ? For example, can I make a prediction for Ic=300, which is not given in the table? or is there any other way ?  @Hearth

@Mhan If you're not in saturation, Vce is set by conditions outside the circuit, not by the transistor.
